# Spawning sprites not working

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

Ok I'm fairly new to coding with sprite kit so I don't know too much. I'm trying to make 5 bricks spawn above the scene and then slide down into the scene every 5 seconds. I thought this code would work but it does absolutely nothing to my scene.

I have another method that has bricks already loaded into the scene and that works so I don't think that would affect this much but not really sure.

```
-(void) spawnMoreBricks:(CGSize)size {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        SKSpriteNode *brick = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"brick"];
        //resize bricks
        brick.size = CGSizeMake(60, 30);
        //position it
        brick.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height);

        SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:5];
        SKAction *spawn = [SKAction scaleTo:1 duration:0];
        SKAction *move = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-80 duration:3];
        SKAction *spawnSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, spawn, move]];

        [self runAction:spawnSequence];



    }
}
```

Comment: In my debug area it says that "animating the position of a SKScene has no effect"

Comment: Please don't use the code snippet button for code, it is only for JS/HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:5];
    SKAction *spawn = [SKAction runBlock:^{[self addChild: brick];
              SKAction *move = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-80 duration:3];
              [brick runAction: move];
               }];

    SKAction *spawnSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, spawn]];

    [self runAction:spawnSequence];
```

Here is a modified set of actions to use.  The problem was that you were running all the actions on the scene itself.  The code provided runs a sequence on the scene that waits 5 seconds (acting as the delay), and then runs a spawn action.  runBlock allows us to add the brick to the scene, create the move action, and apply that action to the brick (not the scene)

Comment: Ok thank you @meisenman as I've been trying to get this working for a few days now, I have looked upon that runBlock action and figured that was what I should be using but I'm not knowledgable yet. Appreciated it man!